# How to make the first sentence different from the rest of the paragraph in a list paragraph?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, list

I would like to create a style for list paragraphs that I could apply to the other paragraphs of the document, instead of doing it manually for each one of them.

I'd like to get it to look like this -

> **First sentence, is not a heading and goes in bold.** Rest of the
>   paragraph goes normal, unformatted.

How could I do this in Office 2016 - either in the Windows or OS X versions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this with existing Word functions, but it is possible with VBA.

Within the VBA Editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>), insert a new module into your document and paste the following subprocedure:

```
Sub BoldFirstSentence()

Dim DocumentParagraph As Paragraph

For Each DocumentParagraph In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
  DocumentParagraph.Range.Sentences(1).Bold = True
Next

End Sub
```

You can run the subprocedure by typing `BoldFirstSentence` into the immediate window and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The code will bold the first sentence of each paragraph in your document.